# How to retrieve only the customers who purchased a specific product at a specific date?

Tags: sql, mysql

**Before anything else**

- The asterisked attributes in the relational database schema code below are primary keys.
- Stores with the same name but different sID (and address) form what we call a store chain.
- Purchase entity set contains every transaction (tID) which corresponds to one customer (cID) who buys from one store (sID) on one date (date);
- Two stores are considered to be different when they have a different store IDs.

The subjected relational schema:

```
customer(cID*, cName, street, city):
store(sID*, sName, street, city)
product(pID*, pName, suffix)
shoppinglist(cID*, pID*, quantity, date)
purchase(tID*, cID, sID, pID*, date, quantity, price)
inventory(sID, pID, date, quantity, unit-price)
```

**I provided myself with the following objective:**
To retrieve the customers (cID and cName) who made a purchase from multiple stores (sID) at a specific date buying just **one single product(pID)**.
Let's consider that I should retrieve just the customers who purchased on **2018-08-27** the product “Onions” at more than one store.

The sql-code I came with looks as follows:

```
select distinct customer.cID, customer.cName, purchase.pID, purchase.sID
from purchase, customer, product, purchase as clone
where 
purchase.cID = customer.cID and
purchase.pID = product.pID and
clone.cID = customer.cID and
clone.pID = product.pID and

product.pName = 'Onions'and
purchase.date = '2018-08-27'and
purchase.sID  != clone.sID
```

Yet I tested it and I've been given with

```
31|Olivier|4|43
31|Olivier|4|42
```

*where **31** is cID
**Oliver** is cName
**4** is the pID (product ID)
**43** is the sID (store ID)* I'm not pretty sure whether *purchase.sID  != clone.sID* is necessary or not.

Therefore, do you think that the very last selection is an indispensable line? Furthermore, is there a nicer manner in which this query could have been written?

P.S. I was not provided with a well-established database such that to taste whether this assumption is valid or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JOINs are now for over 30 years sql standard, so please start them.

Comment: as if you would have said that why bother to ask how a list is formed because the concept is wide spreadhead thus you shouldn't. I do know how a cartesian product and a natural join both work but still can't really understand what you answer were supposed to point out.

Comment: Related to the first comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You want people who went to a store, bought a single onion and nothing else, then went to a different store and again bought a solitary onion?

Comment: @BenderBoy Of course they could have bought other groceries along with the aforementioned onion. Hence, whether the customer will buy solitary an onion or an onion + others products won't be essentially important. Thus, I want the people who bought an onion or an onion and other things. Thank you

Comment: Regarding your question on the necessity of the last condition: because you’re using `distinct` AND your selected columns don’t include the second `sID`, it’s technically redundant for this specific case. If you didn’t have the `distinct` you’d get 4 result rows, because store 43 would be joined to store 42 plus itself, and vice versa. Likewise if you kept the `distinct` but added `clone.sID` to the `select` block, you’d get `43|43`, `43|42`, `42|42`, `42|43`. Also, if the person went to the same store twice, you’d get both visits, which you don’t want.

Comment: Regarding a nicer manner to write it, I would prefer qualified ìnner joins` with conditions split up into the respective `on` clauses. Also crucially I would prefer an alias like `purchase2`. Calling it “clone” is like calling a boolean variable “flag” or something.

Comment: You pointed out several aspects I didn't really consider when this code came along. Firstly, how I should get rid of the redundancy you previous mention - if the person went to the same store twice and pick up the same thing? Secondly, why did you perceive the alias I coined - clone - as a wrong and unsuitable label? Thank you very much for the recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you need two joins here. You need to aggregate the purchases, then check `having count(distinct p.sID) >= 2`.

The correct way to search for dates is to use half-open date ranges. You should also use explicit join syntax.

```sql
select
  c.*,
  p.*
from customer c
join (
    select
      p.cID,
      count(*) as count,
      group_concat(p.pID separator ', ') as purchase_ids
    from purchase p
    join product pr on pr.pID = p.pID
    where p.pName = 'Onions'and
      and p.date >= '2018-08-27'
      and p.date  < '2018-08-28'
    group by
       p.cID
    having count(distinct p.sID) >= 2
) p on p.cID = c.cID;
```

A slightly more efficient, but more obscure, syntax specifically for finding "more than one distinct" is:

```sql
    having min(p.sID) <> max(p.sID)
```

Comment: Could you break the code down in steps and elaborate on each one if I didn't ask for too much? As yet I didn't use aggregation functions and its associated methods - having count.

Comment: Which part is unclear? We take a subquery of `product` joined with `purchase`, which is filtered to the product and date you want, then aggregate it to ensure the distinct count of `sID` is >1 in other words at least two shops. Then join that subquery back to `customer`.